# OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture Mapping Issue

Tags: java, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0 and trying to get a basic textured cube .obj to render as part of a import test for Blender models.

Here is the .obj:

```
# Blender v2.63 (sub 0) OBJ File: 'testCube.blend'
# www.blender.org
mtllib testCube.mtl
o Cube
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.250043 0.500000
vt 0.500000 0.500000
vt 0.499999 0.749957
vt 0.250043 0.749956
vt 0.000087 0.000087
vt 0.250043 0.000087
vt 0.250043 0.250043
vt 0.000087 0.250043
vt 0.500000 0.000087
vt 0.500000 0.250043
vt 0.749956 0.250043
vt 0.749956 0.000087
vt 0.499999 0.999913
vt 0.250042 0.999913
vn -1.000000 -0.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn 1.000000 -0.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn -0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn -0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
usemtl Material
s off
f 2/1/1 1/2/1 5/3/1
f 2/1/1 5/3/1 6/4/1
f 6/5/2 7/6/2 3/7/2
f 6/5/2 3/7/2 2/8/2
f 7/6/3 8/9/3 4/10/3
f 7/6/3 4/10/3 3/7/3
f 1/11/4 4/10/4 8/9/4
f 1/11/4 8/9/4 5/12/4
f 1/2/5 2/1/5 3/7/5
f 1/2/5 3/7/5 4/10/5
f 8/13/6 7/14/6 6/4/6
f 8/13/6 6/4/6 5/3/6
```

Here is the texture:
http://i1273.photobucket.com/albums/y409/Gamer_217/testcube_zpsf2hhxszq.png

And here is the render result:
http://i1273.photobucket.com/albums/y409/Gamer_217/TextureBug_zpsjpkb6egv.png

Below are code snippets from the same java class:

Global variables:

```
private int[] mTextureHandle;
private int mTextureUniformHandle;
private int mTextureCoordinateHandle;
private final int mTextureCoordinateDataSize = 2;
private float uv[];
```

Reading the UV Map from the OBJ:

```
else if(type.compareTo("vt") == 0)
{
    uv[u]=Float.valueOf(line[1]);
    u++;
    uv[u]=1.0f-Float.valueOf(line[2]);
    u++;
}
```

Texture Coordinate Buffer and loading the BMP:

```
ByteBuffer tb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uv.length*4);
tb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
texBuffer = tb.asFloatBuffer();
texBuffer.put(uv);
texBuffer.position(0);

mTextureHandle = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, mTextureHandle, 0);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
InputStream in = mgr.open("testcube.bmp");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureHandle[0]);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
bitmap.recycle();
```

The draw function:

```
GLES20.glEnable( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST );
GLES20.glDepthFunc( GLES20.GL_LEQUAL );
GLES20.glDepthMask( true );
GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uTexture");
mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vTexCoordinate");
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);

mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, face_v.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
```

And finally the shader code:

```
private final String vertexShaderCode =
"uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
"attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
"attribute vec2 vTexCoordinate;" +
"varying vec2 oTexCoordinate;" +
"void main() {" +
    "oTexCoordinate = vTexCoordinate;" +
    " gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
"}";
private final String fragmentShaderCode =
"precision mediump float;" +
"uniform vec4 vColor;" +
"uniform sampler2D uTexture;" +
"varying vec2 oTexCoordinate;" +
"void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, oTexCoordinate);" +
"}";
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when you read in the indices, are you taking into account that the .obj file format uses 1-based indices but OpenGLES uses 0-based indices?

Comment: Yes, I subtract the indices by 1 when I read them in.

Answer (score 1):

The .obj format stores vertex data, texture co-ordinate data and normals separately, and uses separate indices for each. This means that a given vertex position, texture coord or normal only gets written out once, and different faces in a mesh can share a vertex index even if they have different texture co-ordinates.

However, OpenGLES only uses a single index buffer when rendering a mesh, so you need to have separate entries in your vertex and texture coord and normal arrays for every *combination* of vertex position, texture coordinate and normal.

Right now it looks like you are reading your texture coordinates into an array and then passing that array to OpenGLES as a float buffer as-is. The problem is that at no point is OpenGLES aware of the indices into the texture array that are associated with each triangle in the .obj file. Instead, OpenGLES will be using the vertex index when looking up the texture co-ordinate.

So your face data that looks like this in your .obj file:

```
f 2/1/1 1/2/1 5/3/1
f 2/1/1 5/3/1 6/4/1
f 6/5/2 7/6/2 3/7/2
```

will effectively be rendered as if it was like this:

```
f 2/2/2 1/1/1 5/5/5
f 2/2/2 5/5/5 6/6/6
f 6/6/6 7/7/7 3/3/3
```

(ignoring the fact that you aren't actually rendering normals yet)

You need an extra pre-processing step where you identify every combination of vertex/texture coord/normal in your object file. Then generate separate arrays for the vertex, texture coordinate data and normals, with one entry for each combination (it will mean that some vertex positions will be repeated more than once, if they have different texture coordinates associated). For a given combination of v/t/n, the indices into the 3 arrays should match. Then create an index buffer for your triangles based on these new indices.

The other alternative is to not use an index buffer at all. When you load your file, read your vertex data etc into arrays. Then allocate a larger array based on the number of triangles and process the indices from the obj file, copying the corresponding vertex/tex coord/normal into the array based on the various indices. You would then draw using `glDrawArrays` instead of `glDrawElements`

Comment: If the answer helped fix your problem then please mark it as accepted (click the tick mark next to the answer)